# Convert audio to video ffmpeg with a gif as the background but keep the audio length

Tags: ffmpeg

I used this to combine a JPG and MP3 into a video:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i song.mp3 -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

I'm trying to change the .jpg to a .gif, but the gif should loop to the MP3 length

Comment: `-loop 1 -i 1.jpg` --> `-ignore_loop 0 -i in.gif`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to do it with

```
ffmpeg -i song.mp3 -ignore_loop 0 -i 2.gif -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -shortest -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -threads 4 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest out.mp4
```

this worked for me

Comment: This exact command-line worked for me.  This is exactly want I was looking for.

Comment: This command works, but it takes a long time to finish (depending on the audio length) imagine having long audio!!!